# How do I create a SQL trigger to insert new rows based on a value in a newly inserted row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, triggers

I want to create a trigger that inserts 2 new rows based on values inside newly inserted rows.  I am using wordpress.

For example, I have table `WP_POSTMETA` with 3 columns: `POST_ID, META_KEY, META_VALUE`.  When a new post is created in wordpress, the table is populated with several new rows each containing the same `POST_ID` value. But, these rows have have different `META_VALUE` and `META_KEY` values.  I am trying to write a trigger that can:

- Detect when a new row containing a `META_KEY` of **_thumbnail_id** is inserted, and insert a new row where the `POST_ID` is the `META_VALUE` of the **_thumbnail_id** and its `META_VALUE` is a value detected from a different row which also has the same original `'POST_ID'`, where the `META_KEY = '_jig_image_link'`.
- Create a second row where the `POST_ID` is again the **thumbnail_id**, and the `META_VALUE` and `META_KEY` columns are static string entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably something you should be doing in your application rather than at database layer.

You've got functions such as `wp_insert_post()` and `add_post_meta()` in order to easily do this.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with a trigger in MySQL at least as you've described it.

MySQL will throw an error if you issue any DML statement (in your case `INSERT`s) from the trigger against the table (in your case `wp_postmeta`) on which you defined that trigger.

> **[E.1. Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)**
>   Within a stored function or trigger, **it is not permitted to modify a
>   table** that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.